# DBUS Exception when using Quickly

Tags: python, dbus, quickly

Today I wanted to test Quickly. I normally used: quickly create ubuntu-application appname 
to create the files of my aplication. It takes a long time and after a time it says Dbus Exception.
Here the output:

> sebi@sebi-desktop:~/Dokumente$ quickly create ubuntu-application
>   dropmind Creating project directory dropmind Creating bzr repository
>   and committing Ihr neu erstelltes Projekt starten!file 0/1 Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "./dropmind", line 33, in 
>       dropmind.main()   File
>   "/home/sebi/Dokumente/dropmind/dropmind/**init**.py", line 40, in main
>       preferences.db_connect()   File
>   "/home/sebi/Dokumente/dropmind/dropmind_lib/preferences.py", line 50,
>   in db_connect
>       self._database = CouchDatabase(self._db_name, create=True)   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/desktopcouch/application/server.py",
>   line 101, in **init**
>       oauth_tokens=oauth_tokens, ctx=ctx)   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/desktopcouch/application/server.py",
>   line 75, in **init**
>       oauth_tokens=oauth_tokens, ctx=ctx, views_factory=views_factory)
>   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/desktopcouch/records/database.py",
>   line 123, in **init**
>       self._reconnect()   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/desktopcouch/application/server.py",
>   line 81, in _reconnect
>       port = find_port(ctx=self.ctx)   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/desktopcouch/application/platform/**init**.py",
>   line 48, in find_port
>       return platform_find_port(pid, ctx)   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/desktopcouch/application/platform/linux/**init**.py",
>   line 100, in platform_find_port
>       proxy = bus.get_object('org.desktopcouch.CouchDB', '/')   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dbus/bus.py", line 244, in get_object
>       follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dbus/proxies.py", line 241, in **init**
>       self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dbus/bus.py", line 183, in
>   activate_name_owner
>       self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dbus/bus.py", line 281, in
>   start_service_by_name
>       'su', (bus_name, flags)))   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dbus/connection.py", line 630, in
>   call_blocking
>       message, timeout) dbus.exceptions.DBusException:
>   org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible
>   causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the
>   message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout
>   expired, or the network connection was broken. Glückwunsch, Ihr neues
>   Projekt wurde erstellt. cd /home/sebi/Dokumente/dropmind/, um mit dem
>   Programmieren zu beginnen.

To be honest. I had two days ago a little problem with Unity and the reset didn't worked fully and so I just deleted the system files in my user folder like .gnome and so on. That fixed the problem with unity but may I deleted some other files which are important. I actually don't know. At the end it says ti created the project succesfully but it doesn't start the app and also not with the command quickly run it just does nothing then. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 64Bit.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to just delete directories like that. And I don't know what you mean by "and so on". But it seems that the problem is with setting up your DesktopCouch, which in this case probably won't prevent you from start programming. There have been some issues with DesktopCouch lately, so unless you're experiencing other issues with your system, I would just ignore them for now.

You should also confirm that DesktopCouch is running by opening file:///home/YOUR_USERNAME/.local/share/desktop-couch/couchdb.html (remember to change to your own username). This will present you with a webpage where you can look at your databases.

Comment: Of course I know that deleting like that isn't good. I know that I can start programming but the application doesn't start actually when I want to. I can see the CouchDB site and my databases. Could you help me because it has no sense to programm if I can't start it.